# Change string in string[] files = File.ReadAllLines(csspath);

Tags: c#, regex, backend

I try to change *string* in *array* that created from the function 
`File.ReadAllLines(csspath)`.

What I try to do is using `Regex.Replace` and *assign the output* to the `string`(`file` in this case) that i work with.
in the function, I get the array and the string I want to change my string to.

The *problem* is that when I use `file.Replace(file, outp);` i need to save the new array and I don't think I know how to approach to this.
how should i approach this solution?

I also think to use `Regex.Match` function but I get here the match and not the replace.

```
private static void MyFunction(string[] files,string changeto)
{
    var outp = "";

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (file.Contains("font-family"))
        {
            //var match = Regex.Match(file, "'.*';");

            outp = Regex.Replace(file, "'.*';", changeto);

            file.Replace(file, outp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not a good enough problem description. You need to be more specific on what you expect to happen and what is actually happening. Please edit your question and add those details.

Comment: Make sure that the string is match with the Regex expression first

Comment: Are you sure there is a `'` inside the filename? Because I see them in the `Regex`.

Comment: You need to included a clear problem statement, its not clear what is wrong, or what you want this to do.  It kind of looks like you want to change the file extensions, but the generically named method, and the lack of description makes it unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest *design changing*: let the method *return* changes (instead of being `void`):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> MyFuction(IEnumerable<string> lines, string changeTo) {
  return lines
    .Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, "'.*';", changeTo)); 
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
// 1. Read lines from the file
// 2. Make required changes
// 3. Organize the final result as an array
string[] data = MyFuction(File.ReadLines(csspath))
  .ToArray();
```

Or you can even *get rid* of the method at all and have a *readable* code:

```
string[] data = File
  .ReadLines(csspath)                                     // read file
  .Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, "'.*';", changeTo)) // make changes
  .ToArray();                                             // materialize as an array
```

Comment: Thank you very much its Working!.